# PHP MYSQL PREPARE synstax issue (unexpected T_STRING)

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error, prepare

I'm new to sql and PHP. So far have been able to figure things out but the PREPARE statement is giving me syntax issues (maybe because I'm trying to do several things in one step).  If someone could let me know where my syntax is messing up that would be great.

In addition the code I'm writing is trying to update save files on a server and while I believe doing it with a prepare statement is the correct way I would be happy to hear if it is not. *Note* I plan to change INSERT INTO -> a conditional insert or update.

The error I get is unexpected T_STRING. I've marked the line of the error in the code.

```
$sql='PREPARE statement FROM "INSERT INTO buildings VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE id="$id" AND ind="$i""';
$result=mysql_query($sql);
for($i=0;$i<1600;$i+=1){
    if(isset($_POST['ind'.$i])){
        $bind=$_POST['bind'.$i];
        $time=$_POST['time'.$i];
        $level=$_POST['level'.$i];
        $p1ind=$_POST['p1ind'.$i];
        $p1state=$_POST['p1state'.$i];
        $p1time=$_POST['p1time'.$i];
        $p2ind=$_POST['p2ind'.$i];
        $p2state=$_POST['p2state'.$i];
        $p2time=$_POST['p2time'.$i];
        $p3ind=$_POST['p3ind'.$i];
        $p3state=$_POST['p3state'.$i];
        $p3time=$_POST['p3time'.$i];
        $p4ind=$_POST['p4ind'.$i];
        $p4state=$_POST['p4state'.$i];
        $p4time=$_POST['p4time'.$i];
        $p5ind=$_POST['p5ind'.$i];
        $p5state=$_POST['p5state'.$i];
        $p5time=$_POST['p5time'.$i];

        $sql = 'SET @bind="$bind",'. //<-line of error
        '@time="$time",'.
        '@level="$level",'.
        '@p1ind="$p1ind",'.
        '@p1state="$p1state",'.
        '@p1time="$p1time",'.
        '@p2ind="$p2ind",'.
        '@p2state="$p2state",'.
        '@p2time="$p2time",'.
        '@p3ind="$p3ind",'.
        '@p3state="$p3state",'.
        '@p3time="$p3time",'.
        '@p4ind="$p4ind",'.
        '@p4state="$p4state",'.
        '@p4time="$p4time",'.
        '@p5ind="$p5ind",'.
        '@p5state="$p5state",'.
        '@p5time="$p5time",'.
        '@id="$id",'.
        '@ind="$i"';
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $sql='EXECUTE statement USING @id,@time,@level,@p1ind,@p1state,@p1time,@p2ind,@p2state,@p2time,@p3ind,@p3state,@p3time,@p4ind,@p4state,@p4time,
        @p5ind,@p5state,@p5time,@ind,@bind';
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result){
            die("saveArry[0]=".mysql_error().";");
        }else{
            die("saveArry[0]='saved';");
        }
    }
}
$sql='DEALLOCA PREPARE statement';
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

*Update* I am unable to install PDO on my hosts servers and therefore PDO is unfortunately an unacceptable solution.  My answer (now with no errors!):

```
    if(isset($_POST['ind'])){
    $ind=sanitizeString($_POST['ind']);
    $bind=sanitizeString($_POST['bind']);
    $time=sanitizeString($_POST['time']);
    $level=sanitizeString($_POST['level']);
    $p1ind=sanitizeString($_POST['p1ind']);
    $p1state=sanitizeString($_POST['p1state']);
    $p1time=sanitizeString($_POST['p1time']);
    $p2ind=sanitizeString($_POST['p2ind']);
    $p2state=sanitizeString($_POST['p2state']);
    $p2time=sanitizeString($_POST['p2time']);
    $p3ind=sanitizeString($_POST['p3ind']);
    $p3state=sanitizeString($_POST['p3state']);
    $p3time=sanitizeString($_POST['p3time']);
    $p4ind=sanitizeString($_POST['p4ind']);
    $p4state=sanitizeString($_POST['p4state']);
    $p4time=sanitizeString($_POST['p4time']);
    $p5ind=sanitizeString($_POST['p5ind']);
    $p5state=sanitizeString($_POST['p5state']);
    $p5time=sanitizeString($_POST['p5time']);
    $rot=sanitizeString($_POST['rot']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO buildings (id,ind,bind,time,level,p1ind,p1state,p1time,p2ind,p2state,p2time,p3ind,p3state,p3time,p4ind,p4state,p4time,p5ind,
    p5state,p5time,rot) VALUES ('$id','$ind','$bind','$time','$level','$p1ind','$p1state','$p1time','$p2ind','$p2state','$p2time','$p3ind','$p3state',
    '$p3time','$p4ind','$p4state','$p4time','$p5ind','$p5state','$p5time','$rot') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bind='$bind',time='$time',level='$level',
    p1ind='$p1ind',p1state='$p1state',p1time='$p1time',p2ind='$p2ind',p2state='$p2state',p2time='$p2time',p3ind='$p3ind',p3state='$p3state',
    p3time='$p3time',p4ind='$p4ind',p4state='$p4state',p4time='$p4time',p5ind='$p5ind',p5state='$p5state',p5time='$p5time',rot='$rot'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        die("saveArry[0]=".mysql_error().";");
    }else{
        die("saveArry[0]=saved;");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The single and double quotes are interchanged in that line, should be,

```
 $sql = "SET @bind='$bind', 
    @time='$time',
    @level='$level',
    @p1ind='$p1ind',
    @p1state='$p1state',
    @p1time='$p1time',
    @p2ind='$p2ind',
    @p2state='$p2state',
    @p2time='$p2time',
    @p3ind='$p3ind',
    @p3state='$p3state',
    @p3time='$p3time',
    @p4ind='$p4ind',
    @p4state='$p4state',
    @p4time='$p4time',
    @p5ind='$p5ind',
    @p5state='$p5state',
    @p5time='$p5time',
    @id='$id',
    @ind='$i'";
```

Comment: [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) will probably be cleaner to read.

Comment: I'll make the change and see if that helps.

Comment: Made the change and now get this error saveArry[0]=Unknown prepared statement handler (statement) given to EXECUTE; (saveArry is just where the error goes currently)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of deprecated mysql_* functions. It is doing the hard work with prepared statements for you transparently.

As EthanB pointed out in comment, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as you are inserting the values directly from user input (`$_POST` variable).

With PDO your code would look something like this (simplified):

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO buildings VALUES(:ind, :bind, :time, :level, ...) WHERE id = :id AND ind = :ind");

for( ... ) {
    $statement->execute(array(
       ":ind" => $_POST["ind" . $i],
       ":bind" => $_POST["bind" . $i], ...
    ));
}
```

The PDO will send the PREPARE and EXECUTE queries for you and escape all parameters to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Agreed. Your `SET` SQL query appears to be vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll look into it.  Again I'm just now moving on past basic query and insert functionality.

Comment: @Ethan.  I can use my strip escape characters function but I thought part of the appeal of prepared statements were that they were immune to basic sql injection?

Comment: @Tyler The prepared statements are immune to SQL if you pass all potentially dangerous parameters through a bind function which handles escaping.

Comment: @Tyler Prepared statements [the PDO way](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) are immune to SQL injection. But what if someone POSTs some crazy values? (For example, containing quotes and/or backslashes.) Your SET query doesn't look safe.

Comment: Ok, updated my question.  I thought the error was not defining id with the : notation but when I tried ":id"=>$_SESSION['id']; I get a syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Comment: @Petr  I had assumed the at symbol was binding the php $ variables to the prepare statement.  Obviously I am mistaken.

Comment: @Tyler it's because you don't have $pdo variable defined ... please check the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: @Petr could not find driver error.  Looks like PDO isn't a default library within PHP, but needs to be installed on the DBMS?  Either that or I need to supply the hosts DNS now?  I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: OK on further review to get PDO working I need to install it on the server.  Since I don't host the servers myself it won't be an option (I can look into seeing if it's an option with my host -currently godaddy :/- ).  If not I will have to figure out a different solution. *update* my current hosting plan does not support PDO.  I will have to find a different solution.

Comment: Yeah godaddy on their basic hosting package doesn't have the drivers for PDO installed.